# For every other output in php

Tags: php, css

So I have a $res

```
$res = $conn->query("SELECT username, Hours,joined FROM users ORDER by Hours DESC LIMIT 10");
```

which leads to this table:

```
while ($row =$res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>" .$row["username"] ."</td><td>"
. $row["Hours"]."</td><td>".$row["joined"]."</td></tr>"; 


    }
```

Then using html and css:

```
table, td, th {
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    font-size:20px;

    left:20px;
    th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;

}
```

How do I make the first output a certain color, which in this case would be #F2F2F2(light gray) background. Then a second output(column) a white background color? Then third output #F2F2F2 again, so it's basically every other time. I am thinking about an if statement? but couldn't exactly think of a specific one. So far I am getting, as planned, a ugly pure gray back grounded table.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in your CSS for the first selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way:

```
$i=0;
    while ($row =$res->fetch_assoc()){
        $bg="";
        if ($i & 1) $bg=' bgcolor="#f2f2f2"';

        echo "<tr$bg><td>" .$row["username"] ."</td><td>"
    . $row["Hours"]."</td><td>".$row["joined"]."</td></tr>"; 
        $i++;

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing anything. I don't quite comprehend this code and it doesn't do much other than re-echoing the table that I deleted

Comment: @HenryLi I don't think so. Every odd time through the loop the background color of the <tr> is set to #f2f2f2. using the $bg variable. The $i variable controls that. It is ANDed with 1 and will be non-zero (or true in this case) when it is an odd number.

Comment: Am i implementing it correctly? <?php
if ($res->num_rows > 0){
 $res->data_seek(0);
 echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Hours</th><th>Date Joined</th></tr>";
 
 $i=0;
    while ($row =$res->fetch_assoc()){
        $bg="";
        if ($i & 1) $bg=' bgcolor="#ffffff"';

        echo "<tr$bg><td>" .$row["username"] ."</td><td>"
    . $row["Hours"]."</td><td>".$row["joined"]."</td></tr>"; 
        $i++;

   
 } 
 
}else {   
 
 echo "No rows selected";
 
 
 
}

  ?>

Comment: worked like a charm, I just had css at the top which messed with it. Gee thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a cleaner way to do it with CSS3 you can do this without using php using the nth_child() selector like this

```
table, td, th {
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    font-size:20px;

    left:20px;
    th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;

}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color:#fff
}
```

In your case this makes all the even table rows i.e 2,4,6.... have a background color of white, you can also change the argument even to odd, depending on how you want to use it. It should also be noted that Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute -- Add a snippet (ctl + k or the button with <>) and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Much better to do it this way with CSS rather than in PHP.

Comment: I agree. However, since this was such a novice question I thought it better to show the logic behind it in something simple like PHP without adding the additional complexity of CSS. CSS is always better for this type of presentation.